# how to get all array values in one value?

Tags: angular, typescript, for-loop

this is a code fragment

```
<span *ngFor="let rel of item.daysOfWeek">{{rel.name}} ,</span>
```

how can i get all values from item.daysOfWeek in one value and then display it without ngFor?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo i tried sum daysOfWeek values in oninit, also i try make custom component but no results

Comment: Do you require each value to be wrapped in a `<span>`?

Comment: @Reactgular I don't need  each value to be wrapped in a `<span>`, i need 1 `<span>` with all array values in 1 variable

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**`join`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) along with [**`map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method on your `daysOfWeek` Array.

Try this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  item = {
    daysOfWeek: [
      { name: 'Monday' },
      { name: 'Tuesday' },
      { name: 'Wednesday' },
      { name: 'Thursday' },
      { name: 'Friday' },
      { name: 'Saturday' },
      { name: 'Sunday' },
    ]
  }
  daysOfTheWeek = this.item.daysOfWeek.map(rel => rel.name).join(' ,');
}
```

And in your Template:

```
<span>{{ daysOfTheWeek }}</span>
```

Comment: I don't think Angular allows this kind of code in expressions.

Comment: @Reactgular, my bad. You're right. I got an error. I'm not sure why it worked the first time. Maybe I misread something. Anyway, thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer :)